# Passing Data From AppDelegate to TableViewController Without NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, appdelegate

I'm testing a Swift sample project by Apple, Inc. It's called [Table Search with `UISearchController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html).  I've tried it.  It runs.  So I've made a sample from scratch in Swift 3.  Anyway, the following is what I have.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Product is a data model class.
        let products = [
            Product(hardwareType: Product.deviceTypeTitle, title: Product.Hardware.iPhone.rawValue, yearIntroduced: 2007, introPrice: 599.00),
            Product(hardwareType: Product.deviceTypeTitle, title: Product.Hardware.iPod.rawValue, yearIntroduced: 2001, introPrice: 399.00), ...
        ]

        let navController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        let tableViewController = navController.viewControllers.first as! MainTableViewController
        tableViewController.products = products
        return true
    }
}

// MainTableViewController, BaseTableViewController are subclasses of UITableViewController
class MainTableViewController: BaseTableViewController {
    var products = [Product]()

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return products.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(BaseTableViewController.tableViewCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let product = products[indexPath.row]
        configureCell(cell, forProduct: product)
        return cell
    }
}
```

As `AppDelegate` implies, this table view controller has a navigation bar.  And AppDelegate will successfully pass data to the table view controller.  What if it doesn't?  So I have the following.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        let products = [ ... ]

        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tableViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tableController") as! MainTableViewController
        tableViewController.data = dataSet
        return true
    }
}
```

And the `tableViewController` never gets data from `AppDelegate` in a timely manner.  I know how to change it so that the table view controller itself will get data from AppDelegate.  But how can I make AppDelegate push data to the table view controller?  Do I have to use the protocol for this process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `rootViewController` is `MainTableViewController` instead of `UINavigationController` then type cast it to that particular ViewController and pass data to it.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Product is a data model class.
    let products = [
        Product(hardwareType: Product.deviceTypeTitle, title: Product.Hardware.iPhone.rawValue, yearIntroduced: 2007, introPrice: 599.00),
        Product(hardwareType: Product.deviceTypeTitle, title: Product.Hardware.iPod.rawValue, yearIntroduced: 2001, introPrice: 399.00), ...
    ]

    if let tableViewController = window!.rootViewController as? MainTableViewController {
        tableViewController.products = products
    }
    return true
}
```

If your `MainTableViewController` is not `rootViewController` then you can use its shared instance within your `MainTableViewController` but for that you need to create instance property inside `AppDelegate` with type you want in your case it is `[Product]`.

**AppDelegate**

var products = Product

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
// Product is a data model class.
    self.products = [
        Product(hardwareType: Product.deviceTypeTitle, title: Product.Hardware.iPhone.rawValue, yearIntroduced: 2007, introPrice: 599.00),
        Product(hardwareType: Product.deviceTypeTitle, title: Product.Hardware.iPod.rawValue, yearIntroduced: 2001, introPrice: 399.00), ...
     ]
```

Now in `MainTableViewController` access that array like this.

```
if let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {
    self.data = delegate.products
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  It's actually tableViewController.data = dataSet , though.  Do you have any idea what would be if MainTableViewController is not the rootViewController?

Comment: @ElTomato Check the edited answer for that requirements.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ElTomato Welcome mate :)